# Azure Bot Creation with Natural Language understanding(LUIS)

Tags: node.js, twilio, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

I am facing issues while building a Voice bot using nodejs in Microsoft Azure, Currently i have made some research and built a sample chatbot which works fine using nodejs.

I have tried MS portals for voice bot integration and unable to take it forward, need guidance and suggestions.

My idea is getting a number from Twilio, then put my azure bot's end point URL in the twilio number.

Once my twilio gets an incoming call it will route the request to the Azure bot which will respond with a greeting and ask for few inputs, then the recorded voice should be passed to the LUIS app for Natural Language understanding and give the required text which will be further handled by the Azure bot.

I am not sure whether this is good solution, please suggest
I am not able to see any sample code for nodejs. Steps for integration and a basic sample code is what i need as a basic to start with, Your inputs/suggestions on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Bot Framework SDK for Node.js, you can specify text to be spoken by your bot on a speech-enabled channel in either of the following ways:

1. Set the `IMessage.speak` property and send the message using the `session.send()` method
2. Send the message using the `session.say()` method (passing parameters that specify display text, speech text, and options)
3. Send the message using a built-in prompt (specifying options `speak` and `retrySpeak`).

Feel free to review the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-text-to-speech?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) provided and [sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/v3-sdk-samples/Node/demo-RollerSkill) for more details.

**Update**

- Also check out [Connect a bot to Twilio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-twilio?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the documentation given is for Cortana as a channel. I want to use normal PSTN calling, something like this https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-ivr/blob/master/EnableTelephony.md , but i am unable to see telephony as a channel to select in my web app bot channels. Can you suggest how to connect real phone number to my web app bot and use LUIS

Comment: Yea, you'd need to request for access since Telephony is currently in private preview as mentioned in the document and application is closed until later this year (after Microsoft Ignite 2020). On the other hand, Twilio channel supports connecting real phone numbers (link provided above).